# I'm trying to convert a tuple to a list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm trying to turn this:

`('a','b',['a1','b1','b3',('a2',('ab','bd','cd'),'b2','c2')])`

into this:

`('a','b',['a1','b1','b3',('a2',['ab','bd','cd'],'b2','c2')])`

changing the `('ab', 'bd', 'cd') to ['ab', 'bd', 'cd']`

Comment: tuples are immutable, and your data is contained inside  tuple, so you cannot change elements inside it and convert them into lists. You mean you want another tuple where this elements are changed to a list?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki --  if tup is the name of the original tuple then I assume OP wants to create a new tuple with the same structure as tup, but with tup[2][3][1] being a list.  Since as you mention tuples are immutable, thus, a new one needs to be created for any modifications.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `list()`  function:

```
tup = ('ab', 'bd', 'cd')
lst = list(tup)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['ab', 'bd', 'cd']
```

EDIT:

If you want to get your output, it is a bit more complicated since tuples are immutable (unchangable), so we need to create a new tuple that stores the new change:

```
origTup = ('a','b',['a1','b1','b3',('a2',('ab','bd','cd'),'b2','c2')])
origLst = list(origTup) #convert origTup to a list so we can edit it

partialLst = list(origLst[2][3]) #extract ('a2',('ab','bd','cd'),'b2','c2') and change it to a list
partialLst[1] = list(partialLst[1]) #change ('ab','bd','cd') to a list
partialTup = tuple(partialLst) #convert ['a2',['ab','bd','cd'],'b2','c2'] back to a tuple

origLst[2][3] = partialTup #put the tuple back into our origLst

newTup = tuple(origLst) #create a new tuple that converts our origLst to a tuple

print(newTup)
```

Output:

```
('a', 'b', ['a1', 'b1', 'b3', ('a2', ['ab', 'bd', 'cd'], 'b2', 'c2')])
```

First, we convert `origTup` to a list, `origLst` so we can edit it. Then, we will extract `('a2',('ab','bd','cd'),'b2','c2')` from our list and change it to a list: `['a2',('ab','bd','cd'),'b2','c2']`

Now that we can edit it, we will change the first element, `('ab','bd','cd')`, to a list: `['ab','bd','cd']`. Then, we will again change the outer portion into a tuple as it originally was: `['a2',['ab','bd','cd'],'b2','c2']` into `('a2',['ab','bd','cd'],'b2','c2')`

Finally, we set the element in our `origLst` to this tuple, and then create a new tuple to store our change.

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you need any further help or clarification!

Comment: Thank you, but I'm trying to turn that specific part into a list and don't know how and get ```('a','b',['a1','b1','b3',('a2',['ab','bd','cd'],'b2','c2')])``` as a result not just ab bd cd

Comment: Oh wait do you need help getting that entire part?

Comment: Yes I knew how to change that part but not how to get the full part

Comment: @tomato edited lmk if its good